# My SGS2 got stolen and I want to reset it through a PC - how?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-account

My phone got stolen and I want to reset it through a PC how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have [Lookout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout) or another security app installed? Most of them have remote-wipe features. If you didn't, there's also [Lookout's Plan B](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) from Google Play. I don't think Plan B allows remote wipe, but even still, it's likely your best bet.

Comment: A couple more options that may be relevant: (i) if you registered your phone with Samsung you can wipe it from their site, (ii) some mail servers with high security requisites will have this option.